# pandas loop through a list of dataframes to do comparison

Tags: pandas, loops

Calculation Requirement: i_f, r_f1, r_f2 and r_f3 in dfs, i_f compares to threshold of 0.95 (get IDs great than or equal to), the first two r_fs compare to 0.3 (get IDs less than or equal to), the third r_f compare to 0.46 (get IDs less than or equal to), all comparison results together determine eligible IDs in the first df, in next df, do the same thing, i_f compares to the same threshold of 0.95, however for the first two r_fs, eligible IDs from previous DF compare to 0.3333, others compare to 0.3, the third r_f, eligible IDs from previous DF compare to 0.49, others compare to 0.46, again together determine eligible IDs in this df, so on so forth for the rest of the df in the list.

below is the df list examples and code but I got error 'No axis named columns for object type Series'. Expected output in df1 for all IDs are 1,0,1, in df2 for all IDs are 1,1,1,0,0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],
                    'i_f':[0.967385562,0.869575345,1],
                    'r_f1':[0.18878187,0.327355797,0.100753051],
                    'r_f2':[0.047237449,0.056038276,0.189434048],
                    'r_f3':[0.095283998,0.2554309,0.368240321]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                    'i_f':[0.985,1,0.993297332,1,1],
                    'r_f1':[0.300009355,0.281788473,0.146077926,0.167329833,0.245227094],
                    'r_f2':[0.152293038,0.06668,0.196683885,0.321269411,0.02493159],
                    'r_f3':[0.111617815,0.042016,0.465285158,0.085330897,0.548370325]})
df_lst = [df1, df2]

threshold_if = 0.95
threshold_rf12_new = 0.3
threshold_rf12_current = 0.3333
threshold_rf3_new = 0.46
threshold_rf3_current = 0.49

threshold12 = {}
threshold3 = {}
for df in df_lst:
    m0 = df['i_f'].ge(threshold_if)
    m1 = df['r_f1'].le(df['ID'].map(threshold12).fillna(threshold_rf12_new).values, axis=0)
    m2 = df['r_f2'].le(df['ID'].map(threshold12).fillna(threshold_rf12_new).values, axis=0)
    m3 = df['r_f3'].le(df['ID'].map(threshold3).fillna(threshold_rf3_new).values, axis=0)
    res = (m0 & m1 & m2 & m3.all(axis='columns')).astype(int)
    df['f_f'] = res
    threshold12 = dict(zip(df['ID'], np.where(res, threshold_rf12_current, threshold_rf12_new)))
    threshold3 = dict(zip(df['security_id'], np.where(res, threshold_rf3_current, threshold_rf3_new)))
    print(df)`
```

Comment: res = (m0 & m1 & m2 & m3.all(axis=1)).astype(int) does not work either, error: No axis named 1 for object type Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more generic way to compute multiple threshold for multiple columns:

```
thd_new = {'i_f': 0.95, 'r_f1': 0.3, 'r_f2': 0.3, 'r_f3': 0.46}
thd_cur = {'i_f': 0.95, 'r_f1': 0.33, 'r_f2': 0.33, 'r_f3': 0.49}
sign = {'i_f': 1, 'r_f1': -1, 'r_f2': -1, 'r_f3': -1}

thd = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(thd_new))
sign = pd.Series(sign)
cols = list(thd_new.keys())

for df in df_lst:
    thd = thd.reindex(df['ID']).fillna(thd_new)
    
    # do math operations
    res = df.set_index('ID')[cols] * sign >= thd * sign
    res = res.all(axis=1)

    # compute the final result
    df['r_results'] = res.astype(int).values

    # update the threshold dictionary for each group
    thd = thd.mask(res).fillna(thd_cur)
    print(df, end='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
   ID       i_f      r_f1      r_f2      r_f3  r_results
0   1  0.967386  0.188782  0.047237  0.095284          1
1   2  0.869575  0.327356  0.056038  0.255431          0
2   3  1.000000  0.100753  0.189434  0.368240          1

   ID       i_f      r_f1      r_f2      r_f3  r_results
0   1  0.985000  0.300009  0.152293  0.111618          1
1   2  1.000000  0.281788  0.066680  0.042016          1
2   3  0.993297  0.146078  0.196684  0.465285          1
3   4  1.000000  0.167330  0.321269  0.085331          0
4   5  1.000000  0.245227  0.024932  0.548370          0
```

The important point here is `sign`. Instead of distinguishing between cases where we use the `>=` or `<=` operator, we can always compare to `>=`. Simply change the sign of the numbers to compare.

For example, if you want to check if `0.25 <= 0.33`, you can do `-0.25 >= -0.33` which is true in both cases.

Comment: thanks a lot Corralien for the generic answer, the output seems didn't consider the results from previous DF, e.g. for ID 1, r_results is 1 in df1, so in df2, r_f1 higher than 0.3 but lower than 0.3333, r_results should be 1.

Comment: Sorry I fixed my answer. I have to use `mask` and not `where`! Can you check my answer now?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
res = (m0 & m1 & m2 & m3.all(axis='columns')).astype(int)
```

with

```
res = m0 & m1 & m2 & m3
```

This yields the expected output listed in your original question.

```
   ID    f_f
0   1   True
1   2  False
2   3   True
   ID    f_f
0   1   True
1   2   True
2   3   True
3   4  False
4   5  False
```

If you'd prefer they be integer, then cast them as int in this line:

```
df['f_f'] = res
df['f_f'] = df['f_f'].astype(int)
```